# complete the proof for this statement

Tags: inequality, logic

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq 0 \implies \frac{1}{x^2\:+3}\:<\:\frac{4}{5}\:  $$

I thought of doing the contrapositive but not sure what to do next.

$$ \frac{1}{x^{2\:}+3}\:\ge \frac{4}{5}$$

$$\implies  0\ge 4x^2\:+7 $$

Comment: Are you familiar with calculus?

Answer (score 2):

What to do next :

Getting $0\ge 4x^2+7$ implies that $x^2\le -\frac 74$, which is impossible because $x^2\ge 0$ for $x\in\mathbb R$.

---

We can prove it in the following way as well :

For $x\in\mathbb R$, we have$$x^2\ge 0\Rightarrow x^2+3\ge 3\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x^2+3}\le\frac 13=\frac{5}{15}\lt\frac{12}{15}=\frac{4}{5}.$$

Note that $x=0$ can be included.

Answer (score 2):

Because $x^2+3 > 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you can multiply inequality by $5(x^2+3)$. You will obtain inequality $0 < 4x^2 + 7$, which is true for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ ($4x^2$ is nonnegative for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and if we add 7, then the expression is positive.

Answer (score 1):

You are right

Alternatively, for real $x\ne0,$

$$x^2>0\iff x^2+3>3\iff\dfrac1{x^2+3}<\dfrac13$$

But $\dfrac13<\dfrac45$ as $5<3\cdot4$